# How to delete previous node?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I want to learn more about linked list, cuz now I'm only able to add, display, and delete the last node also all nodes except for delete by its ID. So now I want to learn how to delete by its ID through this method, but this method is unable to delete the first node. In my opinion this method is unable to delete previous node. So I tried to delete the previous node but it doesn't work.

```
void carInsurance::deletebyPaymentID(int *x)
{
    // to remove an element, we go through the list, find the value given
    // if we find it, stop
    // to remove, disconnect the link
    // relink the two values now (ie. value 1->2->3->NULL, 2 is removed, 1->3->NULL )
    int remValue=*x;
    carInsurance* prev = start_ptr; // empty header
    carInsurance* current = start_ptr->next; // the first valid node
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->paymentID == remValue)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next; // To go to next value
        }
    }
    if(current == NULL)
    { // if end of list is reached or the list is empty
        cout << "No match found!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Deleting: " << current << "\n";
        prev->next = current->next; // To unlink the node you remove
        delete current; // To delete the node
        //cout << "Customer with payment ID "<< remValue << " has been deleted\n"; // To inform user successfully deleted
    }
}
```

Comment: In C++ there is a ready-made `std::list` container. This question has been asked multiple times before. You should do the research prior to posting.

Comment: You will learn much more if you debug your code by yourself and find the problem.

Comment: No amount of debugging is going to fix this, methinks. I think CB is already aware that the code is algorithmically lacking.

Comment: @Ron he probably wans to do it as an exercise.

Comment: You need to show at least the definition of the `carInsurance` class. Or better: show a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the problem. The code just needs a special case for the first node:

```
if( prev->paymentID == remValue)
{
    cout << "Deleting: " << remValue << "\n";
    prev = start_ptr; // unlink the node you remove
    start_ptr = start_ptr->next;
    free(prev); // delete the first node
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know about how these data structures work, otherwise, I agree with @ron - use the STL list implementation.

There are a number of ways to resolve this "delete the root" issue, which can be found in a good book.
One way is that your prev pointer doesn't actually point to the previous node itself, but the previous node's next pointer. For the first node it points to the container's root pointer.
Another way is that the container has a dummy node instance which acts as the root pointer and as both the ends of the list.
Both these solutions mean you don't need specific code to handle the end of list special cases.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)